# Possible drawbacks of overriding the entry point of a main program

Tags: c, startup, crt

So I was trying to set my own custom name for `main` in my C program, and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3097897/6850771) answer.

> You can specify an entry point to your program using the `-e` flag to `ld`. 
>   That means you can override the entry point if you like, but you may not want to do that for a C program you intend to run normally on your machine, since `start` might do all kinds of OS specific stuff that's required before your program runs.

What would be the (possible) drawbacks of not calling `_start` from `crt0.o` and writing my own that simply does whatever I want it to?

Comment: If `_start` is not called, the runtime is not initialized, so calling *any* function provided by the runtime is probably undefined.

Comment: Probbly only in cross-compilation (development) would you want to replace it with your own. But then, you will want to override the whole run time and startup with your own.

Comment: You cannot use a a different name for the entry point for C semantics in a conforming C program in a hosted environment.  The entry point name and signature are defined by the language.  It's in any case unclear what advantage you see to doing so if you could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entry point usually does stuff like

- Prepare arguments and call `main` and handles its `exit`
- Call [global constructors](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Initialization.html) before `main` and destructors after
- Populate global variables like [`environ`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html) and the like
- Initialize the C runtime, e.g. [timezone](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tzset.3.html), `stdio` streams and such
- Maybe [configure x87](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_102.html) to use 80-bit floating point
- Inflate and zero [`.bss`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss) if your loader doesn't
- Whatever else is necessary for hosted C programs to run on your platform

These things are tightly coupled to your C implementation, so usually you provide your own `_start` only when you are targeting a [freestanding environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30825151/is-there-a-meaningful-distinction-between-freestanding-and-hosted-implementation).